# Equipment / Workarounds for Physically Impaired Photographers

Tags: equipment-recommendation

My mother-in-law is not only a very talented watercolour artist, but also something of a photographer, although she principally takes photographs for memories rather than as art.

She has recently developed arthritis, which causes her hands to swell.  As a result, her hands have lost some dexterity and strength.  This makes it difficult for her to use her Canon 350D.

My first thought is to find a point-and-shoot which is light and has big buttons,  and I would love suggestions for a model which meets these criteria.  However, I have a feeling that the community here will be able to come up with other more creative ideas.

If you can help, or have been through a similar experience, it would be really helpful to hear from you.

Thank you!

This is similar to (not same as) [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/817/photo-equipment-for-the-disabled).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A thought would be a [shoulder harness](http://www.disabledphotographers.co.uk/accessories.html) possibly coupled with a cable release. I'm not entirely sure where to get the harness, but something like that would make it much easier to handle the camera by taking the weight off the hands.

Comment: Or perhaps a bicycle helmet mount: http://photojojo.com/store/awesomeness/helmet-camera-mount/